# error when hosting Windows Form user control in WPF

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

Im trying to host Magtek card reader into WPF, so i encapsulated their [demo](http://www.magtek.com/support/software/demo_programs/usb_swipe_insert.asp) into a Windows forms user control, when i use the dll from this control in a Windows application, it works fine, but when used in WPF it gives this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ctlUSBHID, Version=1.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

My code:

```
xmlns:mcl="clr-namespace:CardReader;assembly=CardReader" 
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfh"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                 Height="300">
            <mcl:Reader Name="_Reader"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
```

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred the assemblies,

WindowsFormsIntegration and
System.Windows.Forms

in your wpf application?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing the `Interop.ctlUSBHID` file from project's References. This file is not supposed to be added manually in references as it will be generated automatically by `ctlUSBHID.dll` while code compilation.